# HTML content not appearing in table

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying my hand at making a website for my small start up. Now the thing is that I want to make a central area where the background color is white and one where the background color is light grey. I made a table with the background color white and aligned it in the center, but it just appears at the bottom of the page. What is happening?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Memocups</title>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#d9d9d9">
<table align="center" width="50%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
<p><h1>Memocups</h1><p>
<p><h3>What is a memocup?<h3><p>
    <img src="images/img_1_cuponstump.jpg" width="540px" height="360px">
<p>
    A memocups is a coffe mug wich has a customizable picture!<br> What makes memocups unique from all other mugs with pictures is <br>that you upload the picture you want to our website and we<br> will put it on the mug! So what are you waiting for the<br>perfect gift is only a few clicks away!</p>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not the correct format for a table, you're missing a `td` [take a look here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). Also, you should avoid using tables unless you are laying out tabular data.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid all over the place.

Comment: Start here: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Also your p and h tags aren't  closed

Comment: "I want to make a central area where the background color is white and one where the background color is light grey" — Then don't use tables for that. Tables are for tabular data structures (such as you might use a spreadsheet for). Since 1996, presentation has been the job of CSS.

Comment: Good catch @Quentin. You should be looking into divs and how to lay them out with css. Table layouts have been a nightmare to style since forever so definitely look into divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple table with three columns and two rows.

```html
<table border=1>

   <tr>
      <td>cell 1<td>
      <td>cell 2</td>  
      <td>cell 3</td>  
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>cell 4<td>
      <td>cell 5</td>  
      <td>cell 6</td>  
   </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the table should be formatted:

```html
<table width="50%" style="background-color:#fff;margin:0 auto;">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <h1>Memocups</h1>
   <h3>What is a memocup?</h3>
   <img src="images/img_1_cuponstump.jpg" width="540px" height="360px">
   <p>A memocups is a coffe mug wich has a customizable picture!<br> What makes memocups unique from all other mugs with pictures is <br>that you upload the picture you want to our website and we<br> will put it on the mug! So what are you waiting for the<br>perfect gift is only a few clicks away!</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I removed the `p` tags that you had around your headings as they are not necessary. Also note that `bgcolor` and `align` are deprecated and you should be using `background-color` and `margin`/`float` CSS instead. Also corrected an unclosed `h3` tag and added the `td`(table cell).

That said, a table is not the correct element to use for this data. You should be using divs.

Comment: Since this is a layout table (as opposed to a data table), I would add the attribute `role="presentation"` to the table element. (For background, see the draft W3C spec [Notes on Using ARIA in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#use-of-role-presentation).)